# .csv file seems to have a hidden delimeter - recognized by Excel but not Notepad (and other programs)

Tags: excel, csv

I have received a `.csv` file.
When I open this file with Notepad, all the entire information are displayed in one row:

```
Email;Cityjohnsmith@live.com;New York
```

However, when I open the file with *MS Excel*, it displays the information correctly. How can I recognize the delimiter character? Because the third program that is supposed to read this file is not able to recognize the delimiter.

Comment: A semi-colon is just a normal punctuation character for Notepad. It doesn't understand commas, tabs or colons as being column separators because it is not a spreadsheet - it's a TEXT editor. Notepad will never arrange anything into a grid.

Answer (score 1):

So your CSV isn't comma delimited is what appears to be the problem.

The way it looks out of your Notepad copy is that the data is delimited by the separator **" ; "**. This means that each piece of data isn't separated by the typical Comma (,) character, but rather by the semi-colon (;). This is why notepad, which is simply viewing the raw textual data displays differing results than MS-Excel, which is attempting and succeeding to find a semi-common delimiting value in the file upon which to display results.

You may be well-served by either **A)** writing your code to recognize the delimiter as the semi-colon, and not a comma, or **B)** by using one of your tools to do a replace to get rid of the semi-colon in place of Commas.

Answer (score 0):

.csv originally referred to comma separated values (csv). However, any character may be used to separate the values, the most common delimiters are the comma, tab, semicolon and colon. If the data is generated by another application you might need to accept semicolons as delimiters.

I'm not sure I'd write code for the problem as you describe. If I was forced to code it I'd write a short awk script to remove hidden (i.e. non-printing) characters.

I use two tools for csv issues. 010 Editor, from SweetScape Software Inc., will show you the file in hex, so you can see any non-displayable characters. The other, Delimit, from delimitware.com, is great for showing columns. In my opinion, 010 Editor will make your problem (and solution) obvious.

Here is a sample awk script that injects non-printing characters into your text. It then uses a regular expression to remove the non-printing characters.

```
BEGIN {
t=sprintf("%s\a%s\v%s", "Email;","Cityjohnsmith@live.","com;New York");
print "Input :", t;
gsub(/[^\x20-\x7E]/, "", t);
print "Result:", t;
}
```

To run the above code, use the following command:

```
awk -f xx.awk
```

where the above code is put in a text file called xx.awk.

The regex /[^\x20-\x7E]/ identifies all characters that are not printable (i.e. not between 'space' and tilde in ASCII).

The awk gsub statement searches for all characters meeting the regex and removes them.